# using MarketplaceDetailTask on wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I've been using MarketplaceDetailTask on WP7 for a while and it used to work fine. 
Using MarketplaceDetailTask, my app redirects user to marketplace and from there user can install targeted app.

Now on WP8, using same MarketplaceDetailTask, I'm able to redirect user to marketplace but cannot install app, and error msg is "This app is not available for your device" and when i tap this msg, a msgbox shows up and say "This might be because your phone software need to be updated, the app is exclusive to different mobile provider or app is not available in your country\region"

But the same app can be installed from marketplace, navigated from IE using same url, that i used in my program.

can someone help me? thank you.

p.s. before you conclude, please note that, "But the same app can be installed from marketplace, navigated from IE using same url, that i used in my program."

Comment: Can you update your question with the app GUID? and exactly how you're invoking MarketplaceDetailTask?

Comment: Never mind, I simulated user action using webbrowser control(size 1X1), instead of using APIs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to simulate user action using the `WebBrowser` control, instead of using the `MarketplaceDetailTask` API.